# Getting Exact Stream Position After Writing

Tags: c#, filestream, streamwriter

Checking for `FileStream.Position` after using `StreamWriter.Write()`, I'm facing some inaccuracy in the given value, which I verified against the lengths of both produced file and used string:

```
string MyText = "\"aaqnt - bra\"\t\"kkaaknc qzxukrnt\"\t\"kkaaknc qzx xrrqtrq zn\"\t\"arhkxar kq Nz.\"\t\"qkstrkkutkzn xhqnnra\"\t\"knazkxr xqtrczra\"\t\"arhkxar Nrt arkxr\"\t\"qkzNrtarkxr\"\t\"TztaqTqkzunt\"\t\"aqT %\"\t\"Nrtknazkxrqkzunt\"\r\n\"8009\"\t\"9000099989\"\t\"9098-09-99\"\t\"kHbkF09F9Hb009890\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"09,000\"\t\"\"\t\"9,000\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"00,000\"\r\n\"8008\"\t\"9000099009\"\t\"9098-09-99\"\t\"Rbakk9Hr9J0999098\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"99,900\"\t\"\"\t\"0,990\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"98,990\"\r\n\"8008\"\t\"9000099999\"\t\"9098-09-99\"\t\"JTNk99Hb9J0009899\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"99,800\"\t\"\"\t\"9,990\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"98,990\"\r\n\"8008\"\t\"9000090988\"\t\"9098-09-99\"\t\"Rbakk9Hr9J0999098\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"99,900\"\t\"\"\t\"0,990\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"98,990\"\r\n\"8000\"\t\"9000090990\"\t\"9098-09-99\"\t\"JTNk99Hb9J0090909\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"99,999\"\t\"\"\t\"9,899.90\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"99,090.90\"\r\n\"8000\"\t\"9000090099\"\t\"9098-09-99\"\t\"kR0xW8kk8J0099900\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"99,900\"\t\"\"\t\"9,900\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"09,000\"\r\n\"8000\"\t\"9000090900\"\t\"9098-09-99\"\t\"JTNk99Hb9J0099098\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"99,800\"\t\"\"\t\"9,990\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"98,990\"\r\n\"8000\"\t\"9000090000\"\t\"9098-09-99\"\t\"kHFk99F00J9099009\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"99,900\"\t\"\"\t\"9,990\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"09,090\"\r\n\"8000\"\t\"9000090090\"\t\"9098-09-99\"\t\"kHFxX8rk9J0909990\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"88,900\"\t\"\"\t\"9,080\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"99,980\"\r\n\"8000\"\t\"9000090900\"\t\"9098-09-99\"\t\"Rbakk9Hr9J0990099\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"99,900\"\t\"\"\t\"0,990\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"98,990\"\r\n\"8000\"\t\"9000099090\"\t\"9098-09-99\"\t\"Rbakk9Hr9J0999098\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"99,900\"\t\"\"\t\"0,990\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"98,990\"\r\n\"8009\"\t\"9000098098\"\t\"9098-09-09\"\t\"Rbakk9Hr9J0999889\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"99,900\"\t\"\"\t\"0,990\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"98,990\"\r\n\"8009\"\t\"9000099999\"\t\"9098-09-99\"\t\"JTNk99Hb9J0009908\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"99,999\"\t\"\"\t\"9,899.90\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"99,090.90\"\r\n\"8009\"\t\"9000090099\"\t\"9098-09-99\"\t\"Rbakk9Hr8J0999888\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"99,900\"\t\"\"\t\"0,990\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"98,990\"\r\n\"8009\"\t\"9000090989\"\t\"9098-09-99\"\t\"9T9kb9rk9HU989890\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"909,900\"\t\"\"\t\"9,800\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"999,000\"\r\n\"8009\"\t\"9000090009\"\t\"9098-09-99\"\t\"Rbakk9Hr8J0909899\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"89,999\"\t\"\"\t\"0,899.90\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"80,990.90\"\r\n\"8009\"\t\"9000090989\"\t\"9098-09-99\"\t\"JTNk99Hb0J0090989\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"89,900\"\t\"\"\t\"9,990\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"88,090\"\r\n\"8000\"\t\"9000099009\"\t\"9098-09-99\"\t\"Rbakk9Hr8J0990900\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"99,900\"\t\"\"\t\"0,990\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"98,990\"\r\n\"8000\"\t\"9000099909\"\t\"9098-09-99\"\t\"Rbakk9Hr0J0909909\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"99,900\"\t\"\"\t\"0,990\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"98,990\"\r\n\"8008\"\t\"9000090990\"\t\"9098-09-99\"\t\"JTNk99Hb9J0090999\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"89,900\"\t\"\"\t\"9,990\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"88,090\"\r\n\"8008\"\t\"9000090099\"\t\"9098-09-99\"\t\"JTkRF9ra0Jq998990\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"900,900\"\t\"\"\t\"0,000\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"900,900\"\r\n\"8099\"\t\"9000090009\"\t\"9098-09-99\"\t\"JTNk99HbXJ0090909\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"99,800\"\t\"\"\t\"9,990\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"98,990\"\r\n\"8099\"\t\"9000099080\"\t\"9098-09-99\"\t\"kHFk99F09J9099999\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"99,900\"\t\"\"\t\"9,990\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"09,090\"\r\n\"8099\"\t\"9000090999\"\t\"9098-09-99\"\t\"kHFk99F0XJ9098080\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"99,900\"\t\"\"\t\"9,990\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"09,090\"\r\n\"8090\"\t\"9000099999\"\t\"9098-09-99\"\t\"Rbakk9HrXJ0990099\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"99,900\"\t\"\"\t\"0,990\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"98,990\"\r\n\"8090\"\t\"9000099900\"\t\"9098-09-99\"\t\"Rbakk9Hr9J0998988\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"99,900\"\t\"\"\t\"0,990\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"98,990\"\r\n\"8099\"\t\"9000098899\"\t\"9098-09-90\"\t\"Rbakk9Hr8J0999988\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"99,900\"\t\"\"\t\"0,990\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"98,990\"\r\n\"8099\"\t\"9000099000\"\t\"9098-09-99\"\t\"kHFk99F09J9090889\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"99,900\"\t\"\"\t\"9,990\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"09,090\"\r\n\"8098\"\t\"9000090990\"\t\"9098-09-99\"\t\"kHFxX8cS9J0990980\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"99,800\"\t\"\"\t\"9,980\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"909,980\"\r\n\"8098\"\t\"9000090099\"\t\"9098-09-99\"\t\"Rbakk9Hr8J0999080\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"99,900\"\t\"\"\t\"0,990\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"98,990\"\r\n\"8098\"\t\"9000099999\"\t\"9098-09-99\"\t\"JTNk99Hb9J0008890\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"99,800\"\t\"\"\t\"9,990\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"98,990\"\r\n\"8098\"\t\"9000099099\"\t\"9098-09-99\"\t\"kHFk99F00J9099990\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"99,900\"\t\"\"\t\"9,990\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"09,090\"\r\n\"8098\"\t\"9000099099\"\t\"9098-09-99\"\t\"Rbakk9Hr0J0999998\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"99,900\"\t\"\"\t\"0,990\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"98,990\"\r\n\"8098\"\t\"9000099990\"\t\"9098-09-99\"\t\"Rbakk9HrXJ0999099\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"99,900\"\t\"\"\t\"0,990\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"98,990\"\r\n\"8099\"\t\"9000098899\"\t\"9098-09-90\"\t\"JTNk99Hb9J0090990\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"99,800\"\t\"\"\t\"9,990\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"98,990\"\r\n\"8080\"\t\"9000099999\"\t\"9098-09-99\"\t\"kHFk99F08J9090899\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"99,900\"\t\"\"\t\"9,990\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"09,090\"\r\n\"8089\"\t\"9000099099\"\t\"9098-09-90\"\t\"Rbakk9Hr9J0999090\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"99,900\"\t\"\"\t\"0,990\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"98,990\"\r\n\"8080\"\t\"9000099099\"\t\"9098-09-99\"\t\"JTNk99Hb9J0090989\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"99,800\"\t\"\"\t\"9,990\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"98,990\"\r\n\"8088\"\t\"9000099090\"\t\"9098-09-90\"\t\"JTNk99Hb9J0090009\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"99,800\"\t\"\"\t\"9,990\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"98,990\"\r\n\"8088\"\t\"9000099009\"\t\"9098-09-99\"\t\"JTNk99HbXJ0090900\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"99,800\"\t\"\"\t\"9,990\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"98,990\"\r\n\"8088\"\t\"9000090999\"\t\"9098-09-99\"\t\"JTNk99Hb0J0090998\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"99,800\"\t\"\"\t\"9,990\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"98,990\"\r\n\"8090\"\t\"9000099999\"\t\"9098-09-99\"\t\"Rbakk9Hr9J0999889\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"89,999\"\t\"\"\t\"0,899.90\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"80,990.90\"\r\n\"8900\"\t\"9000098000\"\t\"9098-09-09\"\t\"JTNk99HbXJ0090809\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"99,800\"\t\"\"\t\"9,990\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"98,990\"\r\n\"8900\"\t\"9000099099\"\t\"9098-09-90\"\t\"kHFk99F08J9099990\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"99,900\"\t\"\"\t\"9,990\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"09,090\"\r\n\"8900\"\t\"9000099899\"\t\"9098-09-99\"\t\"JTNk99Hb9J0009808\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"99,800\"\t\"\"\t\"9,990\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"98,990\"\r\n\"8900\"\t\"9000099809\"\t\"9098-09-99\"\t\"JTNk99Hb9J0000000\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"99,800\"\t\"\"\t\"9,990\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"98,990\"\r\n\"8900\"\t\"9000099890\"\t\"9098-09-99\"\t\"JTNk99Hb9J0009990\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"99,800\"\t\"\"\t\"9,990\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"98,990\"\r\n\"8900\"\t\"9000090089\"\t\"9098-09-99\"\t\"JTNk99Hb9J0000899\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"89,999\"\t\"\"\t\"9,999.90\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"89,990.90\"\r\n\"8989\"\t\"9000099009\"\t\"9098-09-99\"\t\"kHFkT9F09c9080909\"\t\"09\"\t\"k\"\t\"08,000\"\t\"\"\t\"9,800\"\t\"0.00%\"\t\"08,800\"";
int TextLengthInBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(MyText); // 5127.

FileStream Nonsense = new FileStream("D:\\180415_21569.txt", FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
StreamWriter Insanity = new StreamWriter(Nonsense, Encoding.UTF8);

Insanity.Write(MyText); // Position 0 => 5123.
Insanity.Flush();
Nonsense.Dispose();
```

With this sample string, the difference is 4 less (5123) than the correct value (5127). With my original string it's 7 less (5120).

I'd like to know the reason behind this difference, and possibilities to resolve it. <strike>It doesn't seem like it's about default buffering, since the resulting value is sometimes odd, not even, and it's doing micro-jumps.</strike>

I'm considering `GetByteCount` shown above as an alternative to tracking true position, although it's distancing from the actual point/code of interest, assumes the values are always equivalent, and might very well be fully ad hoc.

Hope someone has a clue on this. Forward thanks.

**EDIT:**

@Daisy + @Jeroen, just learning about BOM, and apparently my original string came from a BOM-less file, while the sample above is of course adding BOM, lovely. Also, I *thought* I tested after flushing as well, but seems I didn't...

Comment: Well have you looked at the value *after* flushing? (And are you able to demonstrate the problem with smaller strings?)

Comment: On my machine, I see a "short" value before calling `Flush`, and the correct value after calling `Flush`. Note that the file is 3 bytes larger than `TextLengthInBytes` due to the byte-order mark. (You can use `new UTF8Encoding(false)` to avoid that.)

Comment: 5120 sounds right -- the `DefaultBufferSize` of `StreamWriter` is 1024 bytes, so without further flushing, it's reasonable to expect the position to move in increments of that. 5123 then is the BOM plus that (with the BOM possibly written in a non-buffered fashion). You cannot, of course, expect `StreamWriter` to keep the position exactly synced with the amount of bytes you've written *and* use buffering; that's exactly what `Flush` is for.

Comment: @Daisy, question edited. Indeed, with flushing and accounting for BOM the numbers make sense. Sorry for not testing w/ smaller text, might've helped, but I suspected size and used characters as key to reproducing the problem.

Comment: @Jeroen, question edited. The math does add up. So, you saying BOM gets written before first buffer? Then w/o flushing & per defaults, I'm to expect position to be 3 + multiples of 1024?

Comment: So is there anything left to answer, here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you getting the position before, or after the call to Flush() ? I think that's where the problem is. Before Flush() it's not guaranteed that everything has been written.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I tested after flushing as well, but I seemingly didn't. Still need to account for BOM though for it all to add up.